# spring JMS error handler is not Invoking

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, error-handling, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have spring JMS message listener container setup as follows.

```
    <beans:bean id="messageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">     
            <beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
            <beans:property name="destination" ref="request.Queue" />
            <beans:property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" /> 
            <beans:property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />        
            <beans:property name="errorHandler" ref="inboundErrorHandler"/>              
        </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="inboundErrorHandler" class="com.test.exception.MDPErrorHandler" />
```

Listener Code is as follows..

```
@Component
public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLogger(MyMessageListener.class);

    @Autowired
    private MessageHandler handler;

    /**
     * @see MessageListener#onMessage(Message)
     */
    @Override   
    public void onMessage(Message inMessage) {  

         try
            {   
                if (inMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
                    TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) inMessage;                      
                    handler.processRequest(msg.getText());                                                 
                } else {
                    LOG.error("Message of wrong type: " + inMessage.getClass().getName());
                }

           } catch (Exception cause) {
              LOG.error("Error while receiving message in MlaMessageListener.onMesage() ",cause);
           }
    }   

}
```

my error handler is as follows..

```
public class MDPErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    /** 
     * @see org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler#handleError(java.lang.Throwable)
     */
    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {
        LOG.warn("Inside MDPErrorHandler.handleError()*** ");
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Why my error handler is not invoking automatically in case of any exception/error occurs in messageListener.onMessage()?

Do I need to invoke it manually?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to configure the container like that.

Simply add an error-channel to the inbound adapter; when an exception occurs on the main flow (incomingUpdateChannel->) an ErrorMessage will be sent to the error-channel. The payload of that message will be a MessagingException and you can extract the failed message to attempt to send to your failures queue. Just add a transformer (expresssion="payload.failedMessage") followed by a jms outbound adapter. If the send is successful the original transaction will commit. If the error-channel flow throws an exception, the original message will be rolled back.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the solution you are suggesting is works for spring integration i guess. Which i have not used in my application. I am using only plain spring jms. No spring integration.